# OnePage Checkout - hide payment method depending on matrixrate shipping method with multiple codes

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, cash-on-delivery

We use MatrixRates to set shipping rates to various in-country destinations with two different services. As a result, one shipping provider has 47 different codes. Terms and conditions for COD are different for the two shipping providers. I've made two local payment modules, and need to call the correct one based on the chosen provider.

I've built on the tried and tested method found here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299718/cash-on-delivery-payment-method-should-visible-only-for-some-zip-codes-pin-codes/29360908#29360908

by declaring two initial arrays in 
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

```
<?php
   $yupack = array('matrixrate_matrixrate_330', 'matrixrate_matrixrate_331',  
    [sequential list of 44 more variables] 'matrixrate_matrixrate_376');
  $kuroneko = array('matrixrate_matrixrate_283', 'matrixrate_matrixrate_284',
    [sequential list of 44 more variables] 'matrixrate_matrixrate_329');
?>
```

and replacing the equal expression the Stackoverflow answer:

```
if($_POST['shipping_method'] == 'flatrate_flatrate') {
  if($_code == 'checkmo') {
    continue;
}
}
```

with two in_array functions, the second one with the opposite parameters.

```
if(in_array($_POST['shipping_method'], $yupack)) {
 if($_code == 'nekodaibiki') {
   continue;
}
}
```

It works! It's great and wonderful, except - it takes a seriously long time.

1. Is this something I can count on improving as I move the site into production and reenable caching?
2. Am I missing a much more elegant solution?

Comment: Where are you using $kuroneko array?

Comment: Do you want to block payment method 'nekodaibiki' if shipping_method is subset of $kuroneko?

Comment: The other way around - if the shipping method is within the $kuroneko array, I want to hide the yubin option. If you exchange Neko and Yubin for UPS and FedEx, it's maybe easier. If FedEx is the chosen carrier I want to hide the option to pay COD with UPS (Neko) terms.